# Send message from Android Wear to background service on mobile

Tags: android, service, listener, wear-os

i need to make an app on android wear that when a button is clicked, a message is sent to mobile. If i made an app that is listening on mobile, then all found 100%. But if i close the app on mobile the message cannot be received. How can i make a service in background that listen for message sent from my wear app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [WearableListenerService](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/events.html) in your mobile app; once you register such service in your mobile app and its manifest, then messages can be routed to that service even if your app is not running.